# post error Required MultipartFile [ ] parameter not present

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, ajax, jquery-file-upload

Does anyone know why I am getting the above error? I cant see why? please see my code below and advise where i can fix this error. The aim is to upload multiple files to a location. It used to work for a single file, however it looks like the formdata or ajax request is only used to accepting one file and not multiple. I am not doing this in PHP, only javascript/java. Please help.

```
    function makeProgress(number){   
      var url = getRelativeURL("web/fileUpload");        
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('number', number);
      fls = document.getElementById("attachmentFileUploadInput").files; //length of files... 
      console.log(fls);
      for(j=0;j<fls.length;j++){
          formData.append('files[]', fls[j]);  //note files[] not files
      }
      //formData.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
      console.log("form data " + formData);
      $.ajax({
          url : url,
          data : formData,
          processData : false,
          contentType : false,
          type : 'POST',
          success : function(data) {
           FileUploadVisible(true);
           $('#attachmentModal').modal('hide')
           $(':input','#attachmentModal').val("");
            $("#pbarmain").hide();
            $("#pbar").hide();
            $("#actionPlanDiv").hide();
            setObjectEnabled('#Upload',false);
          },
          error : function(err) {
              FileUploadErrorVisible(true);
          }
     });

        }

@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver(){
    CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    commonsMultipartResolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
    commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(5000000); // 5000000 -> 5MB
    return commonsMultipartResolver;
```

}
}

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/fileUpload" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String uploadFile( @RequestParam("number") String number, @RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files, MultipartHttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
{       
    for (MultipartFile file : files) {
    try {
        File directory = new File(UPLOADED_FOLDER + number);
                if (! directory.exists()){
                    directory.mkdir();
                  }
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            Path path = Paths.get(UPLOADED_FOLDER + number + "//" + file.getOriginalFilename());
            Files.write(path, bytes);
            logger.info("You have successfully uploaded '" + file.getOriginalFilename() + "'");
            return("File Uploaded");


    } catch (Exception e) {
        res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        logger.error("Failed to upload file '" + file.getOriginalFilename() + "'", e);
        return("File Not Uploaded");
    }
}
    return "redirect:/fileUpload";
}

}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with file upload in AJAX or Java HTTP integration, but just looking at the error it suggests you should have a MultipartFile array as a parameter somwhere, probably from CommonsMultipartResolver? Where does the error occur?

Comment: The error is from the spring logs when i run it locally using Tomcat server, when I execute my code locally, I am able to select multiple files and then when i click on the upload button, it prints the console log :

console.log("form data " + formData);

and errors straight after on the ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use..

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = ("content-
        type=multipart/*"), produces = "application/json", consumes = "file/*")
 public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("number") String number, @RequestParam("files") MultipartFile files) {
```

and also use contentType: 'multipart/form-data into javascript code

```
     url : url,
      data : formData,
      processData : false,
      contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
      type : 'POST',
      success : function(data) {
```

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = { "/fileUpload" }, method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = ("content-type=multipart/*"), produces = "application/json", consumes = "file/*")
@ResponseBody
public String uploadFile( @RequestParam("number") String number, @RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files, MultipartHttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
{  
 
This didnt work, i added the contenttype as well

Comment: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found

Comment: try this code `   headers: {'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'   }` into ajax

Comment: Same error:

2017-04-13 19:24:03.752 DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.976 - Could not complete request 
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
 at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:163)

Comment: $.ajax({
              url : url,
              data : formData,
              processData : false,
              headers: {'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data' },
              //contentType : 'multipart/form-data',
              type : 'POST',